# Pulp solver :How to set a minimal variable production using a loop

Tags: python, pulp

I have this Toy factory LP :

```
# Import the PuLP lib
from pulp import *

# Products list
products = ["car", "bicycle"]

#Profit per product in $
profit = {"car": 8, "bicycle": 12}

# Used resources per product in kgs 
plasticAmount = {"car": 2, "bicycle": 4}
woodAmount    = {"car": 1, "bicycle": 1}
steelAmount   = {"car": 3, "bicycle": 2}


# Setting Problem variables dictionary
x = LpVariable.dicts("products ", products , 0)

# The Objective function : Maximising profit in $
prob += lpSum([profit[i] * x[i] for i in products ]), "Maximise"

# Total Stock amount Constraints in kgs
prob += lpSum([plasticAmount[i] * x[i] for i in  products]) <= 142 ,"MaxPlastic"
prob += lpSum([woodAmount [i]   * x[i] for i in  products]) <= 117 ,"MaxWood"
prob += lpSum([steelAmount[i]   * x[i] for i in  products]) <= 124 ,"MaxSteel"

# This constraints is not working : Minimal production amount should be at least 10 on each products ( need at least 10 Cars and 10 bicycles)
prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in produits]) >= 10 ,"MinProdObjs"
```

1. How should I set a minimal production value of 10 for each product ?
2. How should I write this in a more elegant manner, in case I have 200 products ?
3. Is the Lp correct ?

The minimal production constraint :

```
prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in produits]) >= 10 ,"MinProdObjs"
```

simply means ( in fact, car is an "amount of cars" and bicycle is also 'an amount of bicycles'... Maybe the variables names are not so nice ...)

```
prob += car + bicycle >= 10
```

or

```
prob += x1 + x2 >= 10
```

But it doesn't work as expected ...

Comment: Where is the `minimal production value` variable specified in your code?

Comment: prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in produits]) >= 10 ,"MinProdObjs"  its is 10 , there is no variable , for now ...

Comment: That line doesn't make much sense to me. I don't know the library you are using, but you are adding something to `prob` and then and comparing it to a tuple in one line? It looks very wrong. Don't you get an error for that line?

Comment: This is the pulp linear programming lib.

Comment: @alec_djinn: It seems this is quite normal for `pulp`. Besides its still syntactically correct.

Comment: @quamrana I see. My bad, I don't know that library, it makes the code look pretty different from standard python. I can't help here.

Comment: It just shows how flexible python really is. And no, I can't help either.

Comment: `But it doesn't work as expected`... what do you expect and how is it different to what you expect. As far as I can tell you don't initiliaze the `prob` object, so that's one problem at least.

Comment: Did you do prob.solve()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x[p]` is the number of units produced for a product `p in P`, then you can just add a constraint of the form:

```
x[p] >= 10  forall p in P
```

Translated in code:

```
for p in products:
   prob += x[p] >= 10, f"min production units for product {p}"
```

With your constraint

```
prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in produits]) >= 10 ,"MinProdObjs"
```

what you are saying is that you want a total of at least 10 as production value over all the items.

Note also that your variables are fractional at the moment and that you might want to use Integer ones.

Comment: Hello abc ! I can't express how much I'm grateful  for your kind answer, I will read it closely and try it out this evening ! I really needed your help .